# Merging similar attributes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one XML-File which is structured like this:

```xml
<forms>
    <f form="AGAtam"><na><acc/><sg/><mas/></na><s stem="AGAta"/><m meaning="slayer, killer"/>    
    </f>
    <f form="Adatte"><s stem=""/><m meaning="he seizes, carries away"/></f>
    <f form="Adatte"><new/><s stem=""/><m meaning="he seizes, carries away, takes to a different place"/></f>
</forms>
```

What I want now is an XSLT-template which replaces all the nodes which do not have a new-tag as a child with the node that have such a tag, while keeping all other childs/attributes the same. In this case it would mean to replace the node in line 4 with the one in line 5.

Comment: I don't understand your question: what exactly do you mean by "replace"? All the nodes are already there. I also see only 3 "lines", so "*replace the node in line 4 with the one in line 5*" is even more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be just to remove all `f` nodes that have following siblings with the same value for `form` and that have no child element `new`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="f[not(new) and @form = following-sibling::f/@form]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your input XML has the result

```
<forms>
 <f form="AGAtam">
  <na>
     <acc/>
     <sg/>
     <mas/>
  </na>
  <s stem="AGAta"/>
  <m meaning="slayer, killer"/>
 </f>
 <f form="Adatte">
   <new/>
   <s stem=""/>
   <m meaning="he seizes, carries away, takes to a different place"/>
 </f>
</forms>
```

The template matching

```
<xsl:template match="f[not(new) and @form = following-sibling::f/@form]"/>
```

matches the first `f` node with the `form` value `Adatte` because it has a following sibling with the same value and no child element `new`, and because this template is empty, this node will just be removed.

As recommendable reference for XSLT grouping you can have a look at http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html

Comment: Your first template is redundant: `forms` is a node and is matched by the second template which does the same thing.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the advice, of course you're right. I just removed it

Comment: @user3511901 Glad I was able to help you. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed / solved. In case you don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235